# MS access 2007 - checklist options(multiple) to be stored in a column of the database

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a situation like - the customer form in MS access 2007 have list of documents provided by customers. The list is in the checklist format. Assuming there are 6 documents under the checklist. So if the one or more checklists are selected, all the selected list should be saved in the database column named "Documents_Provided". So in order to achieve this scenario what should I have to do. How should my database field "Documents_provided" should be declared and what do I have to write in VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question heading suggests "**Multiple to be stored in a Column of the database**" is a very bad table design, it breaks one of the rules of [Fundamentals of Database Design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IA4ZUEEPrQU), Data should be atomic.

The system you should be having is a One to Many, between the Customer and Document table. The `Customer` table will normally have the basic customer information; one side of the relationship, and the `Documents` table will have all the documents that pertain to each Customer; many side of the relationship. In Addition you will have another table `Document Category` that will say what are all the documents that needs/can have for each customer. So sample data in your table will be something like,

``````````````````````
tbl_Customers
`````````````
ID  |   customerName    |   customerArea
----+-------------------+------------------
1   |   Paul            |   Bournemouth
2   |   Eugin           |   Bristol
3   |   Francis         |   London

tbl_DocumentsCategory
`````````````````````
ID  |   DocumentName
----+---------------------------
1   |   Address Proof
2   |   Photo ID
3   |   Employer Certificate

tbl_CustomersDocument
`````````````````````
ID  |   CustomerID  |   DocumentID
----+---------------+--------------
1   |   1           |   1
2   |   1           |   2
3   |   1           |   3
4   |   2           |   1
5   |   2           |   3
6   |   3           |   2
``````````````````````

So when you need to get the list of Documents each Customer has, you simply JOIN the two tables to get the right information. This is the standard and efficient way to organize the data. I hope this helps, and you stick to this.

Comment: Thank you PaulFrancis for the information. I want to store the value selected in checklist in the database column of MS Access 2007. Can you help in this ...

Comment: I found some info on storing multiple values in ms access. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-use-the-new-multivalue-field-in-access-2007-2010/... This kind of form is what I am looking for. Not sure how successfully I can achieve my target..

Comment: What you are suggesting is MULTIVALUED fields, which many programmers and DB gurus despise. Because of the fact it is a bit unconventional. Although the JET engine stores it in a Normalized manner, on a first glance it will be very hard to get it right, getting the information will be even worse. So I suggest you try to get the structure, I have proposed. Life will be so much easier.